# how to fetch multiple rows from mysql to java table in swings

Tags: java, swing

i have a swing application which consists of a text box and a button.On entering the emp_id and clicking the button it connects to mysql and fetch all the rows corresponding to the emp_id entered in a table. my code is fetching only 1 row of the mysql data, even though there is 3 rows corresponding to the emp_id
my code is:

```
try {
    Class.forName(driverName);
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName,password);
    String sql = "select * from devices where emp_id = " + textvalue;
    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
    int i = 0;

    if (rs.next()) {
        asset_id = rs.getString("asset_id");
        name = rs.getString("name");
        project = rs.getString("project");
        emp_id = rs.getString("emp_id");
        emp_name = rs.getString("emp_name");
        model.addRow(new Object[] { asset_id, name, project, emp_id,emp_name });
        // i++;
    }
    if (i < 1) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No Record Found", "Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
    if (i == 1) {
        System.out.println(i + " Record Found");
    } else {
        System.out.println(i + " Records Found");
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage(), "Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
frame1.add(scroll);
frame1.setVisible(true);
frame1.setSize(400, 300);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are fetching only first row.. fetch it in a loop

```
while(rs.next())
{
asset_id = rs.getString("asset_id");
name = rs.getString("name");
project = rs.getString("project");
emp_id = rs.getString("emp_id");
emp_name=rs.getString("emp_name");
model.addRow(new Object[]{asset_id, name, project, emp_id,emp_name});
//i++; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You get only one row from `ResultSet` :

```
    if (rs.next()) {
        asset_id = rs.getString("asset_id");
        name = rs.getString("name");
        project = rs.getString("project");
        emp_id = rs.getString("emp_id");
        emp_name = rs.getString("emp_name");
        model.addRow(new Object[] { asset_id, name, project, emp_id,
                emp_name });
        // i++;
    }
```

replace `if` with `while`, for getting all rows in loop.

For centring frame use `frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);`.

According to [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setLocationRelativeTo%28java.awt.Component%29)

> If the component is null, or the GraphicsConfiguration associated with this component is null, the window is placed in the center of the screen. The center point can be obtained with the GraphicsEnvironment.getCenterPoint method.

Also:

1) replace next code:

```
    if (i == 1) {
        System.out.println(i + " Record Found");
    } else {
        System.out.println(i + " Records Found");
    }
```

with `System.out.println(i + " Record Found");` because its code duplication.

2)Don't use `setSize(...)` use `pack()` method.

3)Call `frame1.setVisible(true);` in last line of construction or like next:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
});
```